# Downloading file from BOX url C#

Tags: c#, sdk

I would like to download a daily changing xls file from a box url using c#.
This is the URL: https://samchully.box.com/v/Europe000000

We do not need to log in to download, so authentication is not required.

I found the BOX API, but I would like to ask for help in implementing it.

https://developer.box.com/reference/get-files-id-content/

Answer (score 0):

To use the [box-api](https://developer.box.com/reference/) or the [box-windows-sdk](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2), you need to be authenticated, independently of the security context of what you're trying to access.

If "samchully" provided a direct download link for the file you're interested, you could probably download it directly without the box api.
But since you only have a public link to a shared folder inside the box app, you need to use the box api, box cli or box sdk.

So, if not done already, create a box developer account (or use your own), create an app, preferably using JWT auth (see [authentication guides](https://developer.box.com/guides/authentication/))

From here the steps are simple:

1. authenticate your app to be able to use the api
2. Instantiate a folder object from the public URL
3. Find the file you need inside that folder
4. Download the file (or all of them)

I don't have a console C# example right now, but here is a python to illustrate the steps, the box SDK's are very similar:

```
import os
from boxsdk import JWTAuth, Client


def main():
    auth = JWTAuth.from_settings_file('.jwt.config.json')
    auth.authenticate_instance()
    client = Client(auth)

    web_link_url = "https://samchully.app.box.com/v/Europe000000"

    user = client.user().get()
    print(f"User: {user.id}:{user.name}")

    shared_folder = client.get_shared_item(web_link_url,'' )
    print(f"Shared Folder: {shared_folder.id}:{shared_folder.name}")
    print("#" * 80)

    print("Type\tID\t\tName")
    os.chdir('downloads')
    items = shared_folder.get_items()
    download_items(items)
    os.chdir('..')

def download_items(items):

    for item in items:
        if item.type == 'folder':
            os.mkdir(item.name)
            os.chdir(item.name)
            download_items(item.get_items())
            os.chdir('..')

        if item.type == 'file':
            print(f"{item.type}\t{item.id}\t{item.name}",end='')
            with open(item.name,'wb') as download_file:
                item.download_to(download_file)
            print("\tdone")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print("Done")
```

Resulting in:

```
User: 20344589936:UI-Elements-Sample
Shared Folder: 99073953467:Europe000
################################################################################
Type    ID              Name
file    591676566119    2015 Frieght .pdf       done
file    591665840076    Banking Info.pdf        done
file    869134630385    FedEx SCS Service Type Breakdown.docx   done
file    892046618240    NEW 2022 Milling Accessories Price List.pdf     done
file    892047887544    NEW 2022 TURNING ACCESSORIES PRICE LIST.pdf     done
file    1129055114831   Stock_Report_SCW_2023-02-01-23-35-00.xlsx       done
file    782816728512    TRANSIT NL OCEAN SHIPMENTS.xlsx done
file    591661165145    Zoning Exp & ST.pdf     done
Done
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately the program gives the following error:
BoxAPIException: The API returned an error [NotFound | xg49mhaymb3cmd9.0803f2ebec24b4ce18be5c7bca9f342e1] not_found - Not Found

What was your authentication method?

JWT with Admintoken or Usertoken?
What was in the JSON file?

If I try to access the folder as an admin, I still get this error message.

Could it be that the URL is of view type and is causing the error?

Comment: Hi Goszti, I've just tested the script again and it works, meaning the public shared URL is still valid (at least at the moment I'm writing these lines). I created my app in box using Custom App -> Server Authentication (with JWT). Then gave it App+Enterprise Access an turned on all flags. Finally I generated a Public/Private key which will allowed me to download that .jwt.config.json. Follow the steps on the authentication guide link at the top of the post. Let me if this worked. Cheers.